# When "zoom in" at Facebook, the chat sidebar got hidden, but how?

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, zooming

I am not sure does anyone notice that Facebook can detect users zoom-in level when it hits a level, it will dynamically add **.hidden_elem** classname onto **.fbChatSidebar** to hide it. (Check the attachments below)

[image: inspector]

[image]

I have searched a lot about this feature and found the repo in github called [detect-zoom](https://github.com/tombigel/detect-zoom), but it seems that there are still some problems especially in latest version of FF & Chrome.

So I am really curious about how does Facebook detect this with JavaScript and I have tried it with latest FF & Chrome and it seems that Facebook can detect it correctly and hide the sidebar at the right zoom-in level.

Does anyone know anything about how they implement this feature ? or even possible solutions are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the exact solution Facebook is using but I discovered they hide the sidebar on both window resize and zoom.

My research shows that all browsers, including IE8 and up fires the window.resize event when zooming as well. So by setting some breakpoint when you wish to hide something you should be able to implement some similar functionality.

Quick and dirty example: http://jsbin.com/ofufer/1/

Comment: Hi @Jonathan, yeah I know resize can trigger the event too, but what I really want is how they implement that when zooming. Still thanks for your reply anyway !